# Error reading http header with Tomcat 9.0.31 and Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

We are observing in production, apparently randomly, the following error:

```
[INFO ] 2022-01-19 10:55:42.523 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The HTTP header line [authorization:Bearer VALID_JWT_TOKEN0x0d0x0aX-ClientId: xxxxx] does not conform to RFC 7230 and has been ignored.
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.skipLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:986)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeader(Http11InputBuffer.java:905)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeaders(Http11InputBuffer.java:565)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:277)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

NOTE: In the trace we have replaced a valid jwt token by the VALID_JWT_TOKEN string.

In the error we are told that it does not comply with RFC 7230, but reviewing the trace we do not understand why it does not comply with RFC 7230. We also do not understand why it shows two headers, instead of one separated by CR LF characters.

We are using Spring Boot 2.2.5 with Tomcat 9.0.31

Answer (score 2):

That version of tomcat has a bug related to that error: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64210

The solution is to upgrade the version to +9.0.33